# Rails Error: NoMethodError: undefined method `instance' for Capistrano::Configuration:Class Did you mean? instance_of?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I'm trying to launch a rails application that has worked locally. When I run rails puma starts up correctly.

The server is ubuntu is 16.04. Ruby is 2.3.1p112, rails is 6.0.1, nginx is 1.10.0, uniocrn is v5.2.0

Nginx seems to be running. However when I try to connect on domainname.com I have a 502 error.

When I run

```
bundle exec cap production deploy -T
```

I'm getting this traceback

```
root@ubuntu:/home/deployer/apps/appname/app# bundle exec cap production deploy --trace
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
cap aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `instance' for Capistrano::Configuration:Class
Did you mean?  instance_of?
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/capistrano.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
config/deploy.rb:1:in `require'
config/deploy.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:14:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:15:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/cap:23:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:335:in `exec'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/exe/bundle:32:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/exe/bundle:24:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => production
```

Here is my config/deploy.rb

```
#set :repo_url, 'git@example.com:me/my_repo.git'

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, proc { `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp }.call

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app
# set :deploy_to, '/var/www/my_app'

# Default value for :scm is :git
# set :scm, :git

# Default value for :format is :pretty
# set :format, :pretty

# Default value for :log_level is :debug
# set :log_level, :debug

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
# set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
# set :keep_releases, 5

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      # execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end
```

Here is my config/deploy/production.rb

```
    # Simple Role Syntax
# ==================
# Supports bulk-adding hosts to roles, the primary server in each group
# is considered to be the first unless any hosts have the primary
# property set.  Don't declare `role :all`, it's a meta role.

role :app, %w{deployer@appname.com}
role :web, %w{deployer@appname.com}
role :db,  %w{deployer@appname.com}


# Extended Server Syntax
# ======================
# This can be used to drop a more detailed server definition into the
# server list. The second argument is a, or duck-types, Hash and is
# used to set extended properties on the server.

server 'appname.com', user: 'deployer', roles: %w{web app}, my_property: :my_value


# Custom SSH Options
# ==================
# You may pass any option but keep in mind that net/ssh understands a
# limited set of options, consult[net/ssh documentation](http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/classes/Net/SSH.html#method-c-start).
#
# Global options
# --------------
#  set :ssh_options, {
#    keys: %w(/home/rlisowski/.ssh/id_rsa),
#    forward_agent: false,
#    auth_methods: %w(password)
#  }
#
# And/or per server (overrides global)
# ------------------------------------
# server 'example.com',
#   user: 'user_name',
#   roles: %w{web app},
#   ssh_options: {
#     user: 'user_name', # overrides user setting above
#     keys: %w(/home/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa),
#     forward_agent: false,
#     auth_methods: %w(publickey password)
#     # password: 'please use keys'
#   }
```

Here is my Capfile

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Includes default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

# Includes tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#
# require 'capistrano/rvm'
# require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'
# require 'capistrano/bundler'
# require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
# require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

I tried downgrading/upgrading my capfile. It seems that everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Uncomment `require 'capistrano/bundler'` from `Capfile`
2. Add gem `'capistrano-bundler'` to your `Gemfile`.
3. Run `bundle install` and then try again deploy.

Comment: Thanks that fixed that problem now to debug other problems.